# Changing color of burger menu so that it is not the same at the background color underneath it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a one page website that will have a fixed burger icon for opening the menu. The burger icon has a color the same as certain background colors of some of the pages.  Thus when the burger icon is on these pages it will not be visible. I am looking for a way to be able to change the color of the burger icon when it is on the pages that have the same color.

Let's say the burger icon is normally blue, and the div underneath it is white, here the burger icon remains blue. but if the next div is blue when the burger icon reaches this div it changes its color to white.

My burger icon is an empty div with the below css to make it look like a burger icon. The burger icon is wrapped in an other div with a fixed position.

```
//HTML Code
<section class="buttonset">
    <div id="nav_list"></div>
</section>

//CSS Code
.buttonset
{
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 53px;
    left: 55px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#nav_list 
{
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  width: 41px;
}

#nav_list:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 2px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 0.17em;
    background: #71ADBE;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 #71ADBE, 0 12px 0 0 #71ADBE;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

What I want is to change the background color of the burger icon to a different color when the background color of the div underneath the it is the same as the background color of the burger icon.

i.e if(burger icon = blue & homePage = blue){ burger icon background color change to white; }

In order to achieve this, I think that the code has to be running continuously check what the background color of the pages are so that it will be able to change the color of the burger icon.

Is there any way this can be done? Maybe detecting what background color the page has using javascript or jquery and then changing the color of the burger icon?

Thanks

Comment: We're going to at least see the HTML of the "burger", and preferably some CSS to help you.

Comment: Please post an example of your code or a jsFiddle so that we can work out a solution to your code problem.

Comment: We could use some General Code in HTML CSS and JavaScript ... The most likely solution would be saving the current bg color in a variable and then using this variable to append it to your burger ... I will post an answer and keep it updated when you add more detail

Comment: I have updated my question. I hope you can understand what I would like to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** Based off update HTML and CSS I created another fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/snpsp6as/4/

This is checking to see if body color matches burger color and if so changes burger button to white.

```
  var element = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(element, "");
  var bgColor = style.getPropertyValue("background-color");
  var color = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#nav_list'), ':before').getPropertyValue('background-color');

  if (bgColor == color) {
    document.styleSheets[0].addRule('#nav_list:before', 'background: white !important; box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 white, 0 12px 0 0 white !important;'); 
  }
```

Yes, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/snpsp6as/

This is looking for the background color **blue** and its if **blue** it will change the text to **white**

```
<div id="div1">
  <h1 id="myH1">Blue</h1>
</div>

<script>
  var element = document.getElementById("div1");
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(element, "");
  var bgColor = style.getPropertyValue("background-color");
  alert("The background color is: " + bgColor);
  if (bgColor === "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    document.getElementById("myH1").style.color = "white";
  }

</script>
```

Comment: This looks close to what I need. The thing is that I want the burger icon color to change when the user reaches a page with the same background color as the burger icon. This cant happen once but has to run all the time when a user is using the website

Comment: @user3697612 yes I know, as long as this script is placed in the pages it will run on every page

Comment: @user3697612 update your question with your html and css example and I will make it work

Comment: I have added the html and css code to my burger icon

Comment: This seems to work how I want. However, one thing that I missed to mention is that since this is a one page website the different pages are just different divs, not really different pages. How can I do this to change the color of the burger icon when the background color of the div underneath it is the same color as the burger icon?

Comment: @user3697612 Mark this answer correct, and upvote it, since it answers your current question. Then open a new question with the updated code. Otherwise this feed is going to get way to over complicated.

Comment: Ok. Thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This is just General Code and will be updated when the question gets some Detail.

```
var bgcol = $(this).css('background-color');
```

We save the bgcolor of the background. in the example the background is selected as this.

```
$(this).css('background-color', bgcol);
```

Append the background to your burger in this example Burger is selected as this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the analysis of the color component that you want. Here's an example of the red color (if you had a red and a blue icon):

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="background-color: #F00">
<P id=value></P>
<script>
var color = $('body').css("background-color");
var red = color.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/)[1];
//if red is too intense, we might want to avoid using the red icon 
// (although it would be fine on a white background)
if (red > 100) {
  $('#value').html("too red - choose a blue icon");
} else {
  $('#value').html("not too red - chose a red icon");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Programatically - no.  At least not in such a fashion that will universally work across browsers and platforms.  The most reasonable approach (and the one used by countless corporate websites) is to have two versions of the image, and call them accordingly using (probably) javascript with a simple `if` statement that checks the blue values of the background.

If the background is an image, that gets a bit trickier, and may require manual intervention per page.

Answer (score -1):

Using what I could assume from the question, you are looking for a solution that automatically changes the background color based on whether the burger icon is there (lets go with visible).

```
if ($(".logo").css('display') == 'none') {
  $("html").css("background-color", "yellow", "!important");
}
```

Theoretically, this should work if the logo is set specifically to **none**.

Otherwise, there is additional Javascript to identify if the logo is present and change it to none and if that is what you are looking for you will need to edit your question.

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/bt301sw1/)

Comment: No, the burger icon will always be visible.  What I want is for the burger icon color to change when the user reaches a page with the same background color as the burger icon